# Resize PNG programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, math

I have a sequence of png files i need to resize dynamically to the window size. Some snippets of code (out of context):

```
var scale = this.props.scaleFactor ? this.props.scaleFactor : 1;
originalHeight:number = 244;
originalWidth:number = 744;
height: `${this.originalHeight / scale}px`,
width: `${this.originalWidth / scale}px`,
```

With this I can shrink the size of the png by modifying `scaleFactor` manually to any size i want (smaller than `originalHeight` and `originalWidth`.

My question is if and how I can dynamically change `scaleFactor` depending on the windowsize, for example:

```
scaleFactor = window.innerHeight..somethingsomething.....;
```

Can this be done with some sweet math or algorithm?

Comment: Where/how would you use this? I mean there are good CSS solutions for scaling images when showing them, no JS needed at all.

Comment: Do you want to fit the window height or width? Each image must match the window or there will be more than one image per "window"?

Comment: You can get a scale of X to Y with `let scale = x / y;`, then set a handler to the `window.onresize` event. If you actually need to resize the image data itself consider loading it into an html5 canvas and extracting the imageData. It's not super clear what the goal is here though.

Comment: @Gavin That's rather the aspect ratio, I suppose OP needs `window.innerWidth / originalWidth` ..?

Comment: @ErnestoStifano I only need to fit it to height. It's a sequence of "rolling" png files that I mask to make them form a animation and I tried to resize with css but then the fixed animation would start moving up or down depending on the resizing

Comment: @Teemu oooh something like that but the other way around! With `window.innerWidth / originalWidth` the png gets smaller the bigger the window and vice versa

Comment: I don't know if I totally understand, but @Teemu comment is what you are looking for. If you post additional details I would try to help you find a solution with pure css. I would be very surprised if there isn't one.

Comment: @Pierre Actually that depends on how exactly you're using the scaleFactor, i.e. dividing or multiplying with it. Anyway, you could ask a new question about the original issue you have with the "_rolling png files_", I'd say there most likely is a non-js solution ...

Comment: @Teemu But `window.innerWidth / originalWidth` is just what i need, except I need to make the value of `scaleFactor` smaller when i make the screen size larger and vice versa. So close! EDIT: I solved it! I just change to  `this.originalHeight * scale etc` and change `var originalHeight` to 1000. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this. It'll fire 500ms after the resize is finished and give you the ratio of the new width to the old one:

```js
let id = false;
let window_width = window.innerWidth;
window.addEventListener('resize', (e)=>{
    if(id != false) clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('resizing finished');
        let new_window_width = window.innerWidth;

        let ratio = new_window_width / window_width;
        console.log('ratio:', ratio);
        // do something here?


        window_width = new_window_width;
    }, 500)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Don't calculate the styling in javascript.

Take a look at [calc()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp).

```
.scaled-image {
   width: calc(100% / 2);
}
```